# cytoscape.js: have dijkstra ignore hidden edges

Tags: javascript, dijkstra, cytoscape.js

Calculating `dijkstra` shortest path after hiding some edges, the algorithm still includes those edges.

`cy.remove(someEdges)` gets the right result: the shortest path is rerouted around those missing edges.

Would it be possible, and make sense, to get that same effect with edges which have been hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most functions and algorithms can be called on subgraphs such that the function only considers the subgraph (i.e. calling collection).

If you call `cy.elements(':visible').dijkstra()`, for example, only visible elements will be considered.